# How to remove scatter plot lines when using subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple code where my scatter plot is plotting unwanted lines even when I'm using the direct `ax.scatter()` function. This is my current code:

```
star1=df
star2=df2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
a = star1['Tempo']
b = star1['Brilho_relativo']
c = star1['err_brilho']

a2 = star2['Tempo']
b2 = star2['Brilho_relativo']
c2 = star2['err_brilho']

#the scatter plot
axs[0].scatter(a, b,c='blue',s=20)
axs[1].scatter(a2,b2,c='r',s=20)

#setting small ticks to add gridelines after
axs[0].set_xticks([0.9, 4.45, 8.05], minor=True)
axs[1].set_xticks([90,450], minor=True)


#sin function to pass over the scatters
x2=np.linspace(0,11,1000)
z=np.sin(2*np.pi*x2/3.5994)
axs[0].plot(x2,z,c='green',alpha=0.5)

x3=np.linspace(0,540,1000)
z3=np.sin(2*np.pi*x3/360.062)
axs[1].plot(x3,z3,c='orange',alpha=0.5)

#errorbar of scatter dots
axs[0].errorbar(a,b,yerr=c, ecolor='blue')
axs[1].errorbar(a2,b2,yerr=c2, ecolor='red')


#title and gridlines
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='Período em dias', ylabel='Sen(w*t)')

axs[0].xaxis.grid(True, which='minor',linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
axs[1].xaxis.grid(True, which='minor',linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
```

This is a print of the resulted plot:

[image: scatter plot]

I suspect the errorbar of the scatter plot is messing up with the first `axs.scatter()` function, but I don't know how to solve that. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you sure the lines come from the scatter plot? Did you try to remove calls to find out where each line really comes from? Note that `ax.errorbar()` without `fmt=` works similar to `ax.plot` and connects the points with lines.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suspecting, as I mentioned at the end of the question. Thank you, adding ```fmt='none'``` removed the connecting lines :)